# Semantic meaning in operations between Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was coding today and I made a mistake while declaring an Array of Arrays in javascript (using the literal notation), I had forgotten to place a comma between each element in the array. After some further tests I got:

`[[0][0]]` gave me `[0]`

`[[1][2]]` gave me `[undefined]`

`[0][0]` gave me `0`

`[3][3]` gave me `undefined`

`[3]3` gave me a `SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

`[][]` gave me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

`[3]*3` gave me `9` (Number not inside an array)

`[3,4]*3` gave me `NaN`

`[3,3]*[3,3]` gave me `NaN`

`[3,3]*[[3,3]]` gave me `NaN`

`[3,3][3,3]` gave me `undefined`

`[3,3][[3,3]]` gave me `undefined`

At first I thought that this behavior might be mathematical vector/matrix multiplication, but that does not seem to be the case.

So the no operator between each array is clearly different than adding a * operator, and the * operator itself does not seem to perform neither scalar multiplication nor matrix multiplication.

The minus and division signs seems to always yield NaN and the plus sign seems to call a toString on both arrays and concat the strings.

I found that to be very odd, what is the semantic meaning behind operations between two arrays? To me the thing that makes most sense is to either always give errors when declaring `Array Array` and to always give NaN when declaring `Array _operator_ Array`. But that is not the case at all. The + sign at least makes sense because Array inherits from Object and that also happens if you try `new Date() + new Date()` (and this automatic toString call might be useful sometimes, although I would not design the language this way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the * operator itself does not seem to perform neither scalar multiplication nor matrix multiplication. The minus and division signs seems to always yield NaN.

Indeed. `*`, `/` and `-` only work on numbers, and they will cast their operands to numbers. The array `[3,3]` will in that process first be converted to the string `"3,3`, which is not a valid number, therefore `NaN` as the result. With `[3]*3` it "works" because the array is casted to the number `3`. Similarly, `[3]-[1]` would yield `2`.

> So the no operator between each array is clearly different than adding a * operator. I found that to be very odd, what is the semantic meaning behind operations between two arrays?

If you did place "no operator" between the arrays, the latter ones are no arrays any more. The first pair of `[…]` does build an [*array literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), but all the following `[…]` are [*property accessors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) in bracket notation. `[0][0]` just accesses the first item of the `[0]` array which happens to be `0`.

That is why `[…][]` is a syntax error - the bracket notation needs an expression for the property name.

What you did see with `[…][…,…]` was the [*comma operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to delimit expressions, it is not an array literal but parsed as `…[(…, …)]`. Your `[3,3][3,3]` is equivalent to `[3,3][3]`, and accessing the fourth item in the array `[3,3]` will yield `undefined`.

> The + sign at least makes sense because Array inherits from Object and that also happens if you try new Date() + new Date() (and this automatic toString call might be useful sometimes, although I would not design the language this way).

Yes, the `+` operator is complicated in JS, as it deals with multiple different types and does either (numeric) addition or (string) concatenation.

This is even worse when you use it on objects. In that case, it is tried to be cast to a primitive value (string, number, boolean), and for that the [`[[DefaultValue]]` algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) is applied (with no hint). When both operands are identified to be numeric, the addition is performed - this can even happen to objects:

```
> 1 + {valueOf: function(){ return 2; }}
3
> 1 + {valueOf: function(){ return "2"; }}
"12"
```

Comment: Well I don't know why I have not thought about the property accessors since I use it all the time (usually not right after a literal declaration though). I still don't understand why `[3,3][3,3]` is the same as `[3,3][3]`, it should have given me an error? Why would the Javascript syntax allow me to place commas inside a property accessor?

Comment: Ah nevermind, it is because property accessors accept expressions and you can have expressions like: `expr1, expr2, expr3` which would yield `expr3`, I guess that can be useful sometimes...